# Super simple regex (preg_replace) doesn't work

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

The below code should replace all X's not followed by a 1 with K,
but the it doesn't work as intended. Can anyone shed some light on what the issue could be? Thanks!

```
<?php
    $test = "XXXX X1 X2 XXX X1";
    $test = preg_replace("/X([^1])/", 'K$1', $test);

    echo $test;
?>

Input: XXXX X1 X2 XXX X1
Expected output: KKKK X1 K2 KKK X1

Actual output: KXKX X1 K2 KXK X1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matches cannot overlap. So after finding `XX` the regex engine will continue its search at the third character.

Use a negative lookahead instead (which will not be part of the match itself, but only assure that your `X` is not followed by a `1`):

```
    $test = preg_replace("/X(?!1)/", 'K', $test);
```

This will also make replacing an `X` at the very end of your string work (which would not have worked before, because `[^1]` requires that there is actually a character (just not a `1`).

Comment: That did the trick @m.buettner! (Edit: Waiting for the SO timer to tick so that I can mark your answer as accepted)